Invalid get index: Position on base: KinematicBody2D
I'm following a tutorial on how to recreate breakout and I have my code set up like it is in the video, but I believe that the method is outdated due to the video using Godot 3. I have this in my physics process function,
if collision != null:
    if collision.get_collider() == player_container.player:
        direction = direction.bounce(collision.get_normal())
        direction.x = get_x_bounce_direction(collision)

and I have this custom function
func get_x_bounce_direction(collision: KinematicCollision2D):
    var relative_x = collision.position.x - player_container.player.global_position.x
    var percentage = relative_x / player_container.player_width
    return (percentage - 0.5) * 2

I looked over the code many times but I know it's most likely just because they updated the parameters. I tried searching it up but I can't find anything on it online. Here's the video I watched:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIbQ3jJDBw8&list=PLYcTJBw32KtX2fvOdtO_fS3Nd6sxM71tn&index=5

If you're using Godot 4.x the KinematicBody2D has been replaced with CharacterBody2D which is why it says

on base: KinematicBody2D

since no such base class exists you can't retrieve the property position from it
